# Setting UIImageView image to non nil UIImage results in UIImageView image being nil

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I populate a collection view cell with an image, the code is shown below.

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MemeCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MemeCollectionViewCell
    print("Cell is \(String(describing: cell))")
    let meme = memes[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    print("cell for item at gets called")
    cell.memeImageView?.image = meme.meme
    print("Meme Image \(String(describing: meme.meme))")
    print("Cell Image \(String(describing: cell.memeImageView?.image))")
    // Configure the cell

    return cell
}
```

In the console I see the following:

```
Cell is <MemeMe_2_0.MemeCollectionViewCell: 0x7f8c045495b0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (0 0; 136 136); layer = <CALayer: 0x600000234640>>
cellfor item at gets called
Meme Image <UIImage: 0x60000028fcd0> size {414, 736} orientation 0 scale 1.000000
Cell Image nil
```

I set the imageView.image property to meme.meme (which is a UIImage) in the method, yet when I print the description of the imageView image, it is supposedly nil. Why would this be the case?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `cell.memeImageView` is nil?

Comment: @Larme cell.memeImageView?.image is nil. No image shows, but when I press in the area the image should be in I see the expected behavior (new VC pops up)

Comment: I didn't ask about `cell.memeImageView?.image`, I asked about `cell.memeImageView`. Could you print that? If the UIImageView (`memeImageView`) is nil, setting its image won't change a thing.

Comment: @Larme imageView is nil

Comment: Then you didn't connected the IBOutlet or I don't know how the cell is supposed to be created (from Storyboard, in a Xib, etc.)

Comment: @Larme here's the thing I checked the connection in storyboard. The ImagView in the custom cell for the collection view is connected to the code via a ib outlet. checking the code links back to the correct view in storyboard.

Comment: Maybe a little bit more code and screenshot of your storyboard?

Comment: @antonio081014 i added screen shots to show that the ib outlet is set and the custom cell has the correct class and reuse ID

Comment: right click on your imageview and collectioncell, I need to view how these two get connected via IBOutlets.

Comment: For your first and second screenshot, it looks like you might misconnect the imageview with cell instead. Give it a check.

Comment: @antonio081014 I tried reconnecting the imageview to code the information in the connections inspector looks exactly the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150750/discussion-between-antonio081014-and-joel-j).